# Possible to have a separate bookmarks bar in Firefox's navigation toolbar?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, history

I have A LOT of bookmarks, and so I've opted to have the location bar only show bookmarks to decrease clutter/number of results. However, it's starting to get frustrating having to manually search through my history so often. Is there any way to get the Bookmarks search bar (the one you access from the bookmarks sidebar) in the navigation toolbar?

I realize that I could just always have the sidebar open, but I'm working on a laptop, so screen real estate is rather precious. I also realize I could just open the Bookmarks sidebar when I just need to search for a bookmark, but I can't tab through the results like I can with the location bar -- this forces me to use the mouse or use tab+arrow keys to navigate.

In essence, I'd like to be able to have another location bar in the Navigation Toolbar that searches history only.

Comment: Doesn't the location bar search bookmarks anyway? (or at least there is an option to turn that on under `Tools -> Options -> Privacy` in the `Location Bar` setting).

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to overlook, but @drav-sloan 's comment *is* the answer:

Firefox's "awesome bar" aka Location Bar searches both, history and bookmarks - when you allow this in `Settings > Privacy`.

In case both repositories are enabled for searching, matches coming from your bookmarks are indicated by a yellow star (the "bookmark star") in the TAB-through field that pops-up under the location bar upon typing. And, as requested, by setting this in `Settings > Privacy`, "awesome bar" can also be set to *only* search your bookmarks.